# It's possible to have line charts with irregular data series (not time series) in javascript / html5? Are there libraries for that?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, line, scatter

I need a javascript (HTML4/5) based library to draw a line chart that has irregular data (and one or more series).

Here is an example:

```
x-axis  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

series1 (y-axis) = [6, 10, null, 8, null, 7, 6, 4]

series2 (y-axis) = [null, 8, 8, null, 1, 3, 5, 4]
```

In this chart the nulls are not taken in consideration; are in some way "skipped" and the line goes directly into the next value. Of course i want to highlight the points to know if a point is or isn't there at that x value.

There are some of this charts with irregular data based on time series (like this [highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time](http://highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time)) but i need that defining my own (regular) x-axis.

What do you suggest?

Comment: If you remove all `null`s and sort the values by their x coordinate, then don't you just have a "regular" series of points you can plot?

Comment: what do you mean? it becomes irregular anyway.. the libraries i see accept a linear array of data, that matches with the array of x-axis given. seems that i can't use an array (x,y) values to line charts (in this case i could have (1,6), (2,10), (4,8) etc and the problem was solved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts can accept irregular data without using times.

Basically, you take the example that you posted, and remove the `type: 'datetime'` option, and specify numbers instead of dates in the series.

I have posted an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/TRLhc/